# How to change inactive background colour of native-base radio button instead of no colour in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, radio-button, native-base

How to change the radio button colour when radio button is inactive , the radio button I have used is native-base radio.
If this option is not selected I want the round to be like have a bg colour of white/red or anything `color={'#FFF'}` only changes the border colour , not whole circle

```
   <Radio
                selected={checked}
                standardStyle={true}
                style={styles.radio}
                color={'#FFF'}
                selectedColor={'red}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `unchekedColor="#FFF"` attribute in radio props.

Comment: it doesn't work I tried with correct spelling also. Im using native-base radio